# unable to resolve class XmlParser.parseText

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to parse XML file in Jenkins Pipeline. But, getting this error:

> unable to resolve class XmlParser.parseText

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 252: unable to resolve class XmlParser.parseText 
 @ line 252, column 47.
       def test_report_xml = new XmlPar
                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:321)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Code**

```
import groovy.util.XmlParser
pipeline {
stages {
    stage ("Parse XML file") {
        steps {
            def test_report = readFile "report.xml"
            def test_report_xml = new XmlParser.parseText(test_report)
            println test_report_xml.testsuites.testsuite.each{
                println it.@name
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your code in order to make it functional (I tried it on the console script):

```
import groovy.util.XmlParser
def test_report = readFile "report.xml"
def xml = new XmlParser()
def test_report_xml = xml.parseText(test_report)
```

The only difference is that I create the object prior its use